# Select data within one month prior to each user's last record

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have a table called "Diary" like this:

```
| id | user_id |        recorded_at       | record |
|----|---------|--------------------------|--------|
| 20 |  50245  |2017-10-01 23:00:14.765366|   89   |
| 21 |  50245  |2017-12-05 10:00:33.135331|   97   |
| 22 |  50245  |2017-12-31 11:50:23.965134|   80   |
| 23 |  76766  |2015-10-06 11:00:14.902452|   70   |
| 24 |  76766  |2015-10-07 22:40:59.124553|   81   |
```

*For each user I want to retrieve the latest row and all rows within one month prior to that.*

In other words, for user_id 50245, I want the his/her data from "2017-12-01 11:50:23.965134" to "2017-12-31 11:50:23.965134"; for user_id 76766, I want his/her data from "2015-09-07 22:40:59.124553" to "2015-10-07 22:40:59.124553".

Hence the desired result looks like this:

```
| id | user_id |        recorded_at       | record |
|----|---------|--------------------------|--------|
| 21 |  50245  |2017-12-05 10:00:33.135331|   97   |
| 22 |  50245  |2017-12-31 11:50:23.965134|   80   |
| 23 |  76766  |2015-10-06 11:00:14.902452|   70   |
| 24 |  76766  |2015-10-07 22:40:59.124553|   81   |
```

Please note that the record of id 20 is *not* included because it is more than one month prior to user_id 50245's last record.

Is there any way I can write an SQL query to achieve this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I really have no idea. If you have hints or key words to search, please kindly give some. Sorry for being a newbie in SQL.

Comment: The best query technique depends on the details of your setup: Postgres version (`SELECT version();`), table definition (are `user_id` and `recorded_at` defined `NOT NULL`?), cardinalities (how many rows?), value frequencies (how many rows per user / month; min/max/avg). And is there a separate table `users` with exactly 1 row for (at least) every relevant user?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter apologies for late replies. Your posts are awesome. Please see my comment below your answer and enlighten me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For small tables, any (valid) query technique is good.

For **big** tables, details matter. Assuming:

- There is also a `users` table with `user_id` as PK containing all relevant users (or possibly a few more). This is the typical setup.
- You have (or can create) an index on `diary (user_id, recorded_at DESC NULLS LAST)`. `NULLS LAST` is optional if `recorded_at` is defined `NOT NULL`. But make sure the query matches the index.
- More than a few rows per user - the typical use case.

This should be among the fastest options:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM   users u
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT recorded_at
   FROM   diary
   WHERE  user_id = u.user_id
   ORDER  BY recorded_at DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT 1
   ) d1
JOIN   diary d ON d.user_id = u.user_id
              AND d.recorded_at >= d1.recorded_at - interval '1 month'
ORDER  BY d.user_id, d.recorded_at;
```

Produces your desired result exactly.

For only *few* rows per user, `max()` or `DISTINCT ON ()` in a subquery are typically faster.

Related (with detailed explanation):

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

About the `FROM` clause:

- [Start with the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)
- [Why does this implicit join get planned differently than an explicit join?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167207/why-does-this-implicit-join-get-planned-differently-than-an-explicit-join/167219#167219)
- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

Comment: I have some following questions: First, why does `SELECT d.* FROM users u` in the first two lines work? Usually I would do something like `SELECT * FROM diary d INNER JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.user_id`. Second, why do you use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` instead of `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`? Is it because the former doesn't need an `ON` statement? Third and finally, what kind of join is the last `JOIN` in your demonstration?

Comment: @ytu: `d` is the table alias for `diary` which we join in later. `CROSS JOIN` is an unconditional join that only requires a row on each side - as opposed to `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` which requires a join condition, but retains all rows on the left side, even without match on the right side. `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional noise words. More explanation in the added links and basics in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM.

Comment: I am aware of the alias setting `d` for `diary`. However *selecting* columns in `diary` *from* `users` is not intuitive to me, and I found little information about how `FROM` clause works in this situation. Doesn't the order of `FROM` clause matter? How is it better than `SELECT d.* FROM diary d CROSS JOIN LATERAL` ... `JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.user_id`?

Comment: @ytu: Columns from all table expressions listed in the `FROM` clause (optionally joined with explicit `JOIN` syntax) are visible in the `SELECT` list. Typically, the order of items in the `FROM` clause does not matter. But there are various exceptions, `LATERAL` joins being a notable one. I added some more pointers above.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to use window functions:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*, max(d.recorded_at) over (partition by d.user_id) as max_recorded_at
      from diary d
     ) d
where recorded_at >= max_recorded_at - interval '1 month';
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way is to use a subquery to get the max `recorded_at` for each `user_id` and then join:

```
select d.*
  from diary d
       join ( select user_id, max(recorderd_at) mra
                from diary
               group by user_id ) m on d.user_id = m.user_id
 where m.mra <= d.recorded_at + interval '1 month'
```

this has the drawback of accessing the table twice (may be different in different RDBMS - use `explain` to see the execution plan).

A better alternative is to use window functions to do everything in one pass:

```
select id, user_id, recorderd_at
  from ( select *, max(recorderd_at) over (partition by user_id) as mra
           from diary ) x
 where mra <= recorderd_at + interval '1 months'
```

*Disclaimer* I did not test the queries above, but you should get the idea anyway - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e90000/9 for a working example w/ similar schema

Answer (score 0):

*Not tested* but something like this should work.

I would use a subquery to get the last_record then filter out those at the date and the previous month like for example :

```
select d.* from diary d,
(select max(recorded_at) l from diary group by user_id) as last_record 
where  d.recorded_at = last_record.l
or
  ( 
   d.recorded_at  >= date_trunc('month', last_record.l - interval '1' month)
   and d.recorded_at  < last_record.l
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try that in these days. One question though: for the `,` following `select d.* from diary d`, is that a way to create a subquery and use the result later? I thought subqueries can be written only in `**** JOIN` clauses.