# GROUP BY error: column "f.path" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

In Postgres 12, I'm trying to perform a `SELECT` on the `recipes` table bringing only one image (files). However, when performing the query without `GROUP BY` I get duplicate recipes according to the number of its images (files). When trying to use `GROUP BY`, I get the following error:

> column "f.path" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

The query I'm running is:

```
SELECT r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f.path
FROM recipes AS r
LEFT JOIN chefs AS c ON (r.chef_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN recipe_files AS rf ON (rf.recipe_id = r.id)
LEFT JOIN files AS f ON (rf.file_id = f.id)
GROUP BY r.id, c.id
ORDER BY r.title ASC
```

If I add `f.path` to `GROUP BY`, I return to the initial problem of receiving the listing with duplicate items according to the number of images (files).

Comment: The immediate error can be solved changing the first line to `SELECT r.id, max(r.title), max(c.name) AS chef_name, max(f.path)`, but I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. Please add  a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: So if there are multiple files for a recipe, then which one do you want to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want one file for each recipe, you can join to a derived-table that picks only one:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f1.path
FROM recipes AS r
  LEFT JOIN chefs AS c ON r.chef_id = c.id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (rf.recipe_id) rf.recipe_id, f.path
    FROM recipe_files AS rf 
      JOIN files AS f ON rf.file_id = f.id
    ORDER BY rf.recipe_id, f.id -- picks an arbitrary file
  ) f1 ON f1.recipe_id = r.id
ORDER BY r.title ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per recipe, then use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.title, r.id) r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f.path
FROM recipes r LEFT JOIN chefs AS c ON (r.chef_id = c.id)
     recipe_files AS rf
     ON rf.recipe_id = r.id
     files f
     ON rf.file_id = f.id
ORDER BY r.title, r.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with SQL Server, but it looks like Postgres has a similar function. Try using ROW_NUMBER(). Reference can be found here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

It will be something like this. You will need to modify it to order how you would like.

```
SELECT 
    r.id
    , r.title
    , c.name AS chef_name
    , f.path
FROM (
    SELECT 
        r.id
        , r.title
        , c.name AS chef_name
        , f.path
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f.path ORDER BY r.title)
    FROM recipes AS r
        LEFT JOIN chefs AS c ON (r.chef_id = c.id)
        LEFT JOIN recipe_files AS rf ON (rf.recipe_id = r.id)
        LEFT JOIN files AS f ON (rf.file_id = f.id)
) 
WHERE row_number = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate unwanted rows as early as possible. In this case, apply `DISTINCT ON` *before* joining to `files`:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f.path
FROM   recipes    r
LEFT   JOIN chefs c ON r.chef_id = c.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (recipe_id)
          recipe_id, file_id
   FROM   recipe_files
   -- without ORDER BY it's truly arbitrary
   ) rf ON rf.recipe_id = r.id
LEFT   JOIN files f ON rf.file_id = f.id
ORDER  BY r.title;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

The query should be the optimum to retrieve *all* recipes while there are only *few* files per recipe.

For *many* files per recipe, other techniques are (much) faster:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

To retrieve only few recipes, yet other techniques are (much) more efficient:. Like:

```sql
SELECT r.id, r.title, c.name AS chef_name, f.path
FROM   recipes    r
LEFT   JOIN chefs c ON r.chef_id = c.id
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT recipe_id, file_id
   FROM   recipe_files
   WHERE  recipe_id = r.id
   ORDER  BY recipe_id, file_id
   LIMIT  1
   ) rf ON true
LEFT   JOIN files f ON rf.file_id = f.id
WHERE  r.title = 'foo'                     -- some selective filter
ORDER  BY r.title;
```

See:

- [Select data within one month prior to each user's last record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345520/select-data-within-one-month-prior-to-each-users-last-record/48348377#48348377)